# Maximum value vs selected date power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, inventory

I have the following table where I present inventory information of some materials (for example, dummy data of a single material).

```
Werk   material   description   stock      $$       date 
 us2     1          material1     4      154.15     202307
 us3     1          material1     3       67.08     202310
 us5     1          material1     1        2.00     202308
 us2     1          material1    10      198.00     202311
 us3     1          material1     0        0.00     202311
```

Since it is inventory information, I need to obtain the last value of each material by werk. That is, in the month of November, obtain the following data

```
Werk   material   description   stock      $$       date 
 us5     1          material1     1        2.00     202308
 us2     1          material1    10      198.00     202311
 us3     1          material1     0        0.00     202311
```

The problem is that when I want to put a filter with the "date" field, if I select, for example, "202311" it will only show me the data for werks 2 and 3

How can I put a filter and when I select a date it gives me the last value before that selected date

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show additional rows from a table that has been **directly** filtered/sliced.

So to achieve what you are after, you will need a separate table that will be used for your filter/slicer. Create a new Calculated Table with:

```
Inventory Date = DISTINCT('inventory'[date])
```

Ensure no relationship exists between `Inventory Date` table and your `inventory` table. Then create a measure similar to this one:

```
Filtered Count = 
  var minD = MIN('Inventory Date'[date])
  var thisM = SELECTEDVALUE(inventory[material])

  var prevRow = 
    TOPN(1, 
      FILTER(ALL(inventory), inventory[material] = thisM && inventory[date] < minD),
      [Werk], DESC
    )
  var dateRows =
    FILTER(
      ALLSELECTED(inventory),
      inventory[date] IN DISTINCT('Inventory Date'[date])
    )
  var allRows = UNION(dateRows, prevRow)

  return COUNTROWS( INTERSECT(allRows, inventory) )
```

Now add this measure as a Visual Filter in the Filter pane, and set it to `is not blank`.

[image]

**Note**
The above will include the one row per material with the max Werk before the selected date. It wasn't clear if you needed to show all unique Werks rows for the date selected prior. For example, if Nov only had `Werk = us2`, what rows should it show?

Comment: Hi, i tried to try but when i want to add the measurement to the filter and set it to not is blank i get the error "Error de OLE DB u ODBC"

Comment: Try setting the filter to `is greater than 0`.

Comment: Thanks¡, I have already modified the filter, however, now I get the error "The visual object exceeded the available resources" when I add the measure as a filter, I already tried adding more filters to reduce the amount of data but the display error still appears .

Comment: How many rows are there altogether in your table? What's your data source and is it DirectQuery?